# int OR operation

Tags: java, operators

Can someone explain why the following program printing output as 7

public class Test{

```
 public static void main(String []args){
     int i =1;
     int j =2;
     int k= 5;
    System.out.println(i|j|k);
 }
```

}

I would like to know how the OR operation happens in java int.

Comment: Note that `|` and `||` are two different operators

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is the [bitwise-OR operator in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).  Last 8 bits for simplicity:

```
1 = 00000001
2 = 00000010
5 = 00000101
============
7 = 00000111 // 1 where the corresponding bit is set in any of the above numbers
```

Comment: Why logical operation is allowed for int data type in java ?

Comment: This is not a logical operation, like logical-OR is (`||`), it's a bitwise operation.  The bitwise-OR (along with bitwise-AND `&`) is useful for storing and retrieving multiple `boolean` flag values in one compact `int`.

Comment: Thank you rgettman.. In the above example how many boolean values are stored 7 = 00000111 ? and why it's useful to store multiple boolean flag in int can you give a concrete example /scenario where this can be useful ?

Comment: Here, 3 of the 8 flags are set (not all 8 would need to be used or have meaning).  The flags are implemented as constants that are powers of two, whose binary representation is only one bit set.  One possible application, for example, would be storing font flags such as **bold**, which could be represented by bit 0, _italic_, which could be represented by bit 1, and <u>underline</u>, which could be represented by bit 2.

Answer (score 1):

These values have the bit values:

```
1 -> 0001
2 -> 0010
5 -> 0101
```

when you bitwise-OR them yogether you get:

```
     0111
```

which is 7